# Laravel 5.6 not found page when model is in type hint for parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I have a method to show images, when the image is not found on the filesystem, it should return a not found image.
All of this is working fine until I specify the type of the parameter in the method.

It doesn't work when my code is like this:

```
public function showImage( LibraryFile $image, string $name ): BinaryFileResponse {
    if ( ( $image->thumbnails[ $name ] ?? null ) && File::exists( $image->thumbnails[ $name ] ) ) {
        return response()
            ->file( $image->thumbnails[ $name ] );

    }

    return response()
        ->file( public_path( 'images/no-image-available.png' ) );
}
```

It does work like this:

```
public function showImage( $image, string $name ): BinaryFileResponse {
    if ( ( $image->thumbnails[ $name ] ?? null ) && File::exists( $image->thumbnails[ $name ] ) ) {
        return response()
            ->file( $image->thumbnails[ $name ] );

    }

    return response()
        ->file( public_path( 'images/no-image-available.png' ) );
}
```

I think this is probably because the model cannot be found and therefore Laravel decides to throw a 404. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use custom resolution binding in [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) like this:

```
Route::bind('image', function ($value) {
    return App\LibraryFile::find($image) ?? abort(response()
    ->file( public_path( 'images/no-image-available.png' )));
});
```

to return custom response in case model is not found